# Selecting timeranges based on insertion date of matched result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `messages(id, inserted_at)` table

I want to select the N most recent messages whose inserted_at column is with say, 2 minutes of the single most recent message.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with a sub select in the `where` clause:

```
select  *
from    messages
where   inserted_at >=
        ( select max(inserted_at) - interval '90 minute'
          from   messages
        )
order by inserted_at desc
limit   2
```

... and just specify the interval of your choice, and the limit value.

Note that the two conditions (record limit N, date limit) are in competition, and you may get fewer records than N, or else get some messages excluded although they are within the date/time limit.

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a863d5/3)

If you meant that the date/time condition was to be a *minimum* time difference, then turn around the where condition from `>=` to `<=`:

```
select  *
from    messages
where   inserted_at <=
        ( select max(inserted_at) - interval '90 minute'
          from   messages
        )
order by inserted_at desc
limit   2
```